# Presonus 44VSL has no playback from Front-Left speaker output

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, speakers

I'm new to Linux and I have added a PreSonus 44VSL to my laptop. Everything is working fine except one of the output speakers. I went into System setting for Sound and selected the PreSonus then clicked the Test button. I used one speaker and plugged it into an output jack on the PreSonus and clicked on each of the speakers on the test screen to see what each of the output jacks were mapped to. Here were the results.

Output Jack 1: Front Right << Should be Front Left

Output Jack 2: Front Right

Output Jack 3: Rear Left

Output Jack 4: Rear Right

I am on Ubuntu 22.04 and don't know where to look or how to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I have run the following commands and see nothing usual about the output.  I also have a verbose listing of the alsa-info that I could add if anyone is interested.

aplay -lL

null Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)

default    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server

samplerate Rate Converter Plugin Using Samplerate Library

speexrate  Rate Converter Plugin Using Speex Resampler

jack     JACK Audio Connection Kit

oss      Open Sound System

pulse    PulseAudio Sound Server

upmix    Plugin for channel upmix (4,6,8)

vdownmix Plugin for channel downmix (stereo) with a simple spacialization

hw:CARD=sofsoundwire,DEV=2 sof-soundwire,
Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=sofsoundwire,DEV=5
sof-soundwire,
Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=sofsoundwire,DEV=6
sof-soundwire,
Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=sofsoundwire,DEV=7
sof-soundwire,
Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=sofsoundwire,DEV=2
sof-soundwire,
Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=sofsoundwire,DEV=5
sof-soundwire,
Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=sofsoundwire,DEV=6
sof-soundwire,
Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=sofsoundwire,DEV=7
sof-soundwire,
Hardware device with all software conversions
dmix:CARD=sofsoundwire,DEV=2
sof-soundwire,
Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=sofsoundwire,DEV=5
sof-soundwire,
Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=sofsoundwire,DEV=6
sof-soundwire,
Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=sofsoundwire,DEV=7
sof-soundwire,
Direct sample mixing device

usbstream:CARD=sofsoundwire
sof-soundwire
USB Stream Output

hw:CARD=VSL,DEV=0
AudioBox 44 VSL, USB Audio
Direct hardware device without any conversions

plughw:CARD=VSL,DEV=0
AudioBox 44 VSL, USB Audio
Hardware device with all software conversions

sysdefault:CARD=VSL
AudioBox 44 VSL, USB Audio
Default Audio Device

front:CARD=VSL,DEV=0
AudioBox 44 VSL, USB Audio
Front output / input

surround21:CARD=VSL,DEV=0
AudioBox 44 VSL, USB Audio
2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers

surround40:CARD=VSL,DEV=0
AudioBox 44 VSL, USB Audio
4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=VSL,DEV=0
AudioBox 44 VSL, USB Audio
4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers

surround50:CARD=VSL,DEV=0
AudioBox 44 VSL, USB Audio
5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers

surround51:CARD=VSL,DEV=0
AudioBox 44 VSL, USB Audio
5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers

surround71:CARD=VSL,DEV=0
AudioBox 44 VSL, USB Audio
7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers

iec958:CARD=VSL,DEV=0
AudioBox 44 VSL, USB Audio
IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output

dmix:CARD=VSL,DEV=0
AudioBox 44 VSL, USB Audio
Direct sample mixing device

usbstream:CARD=VSL
AudioBox 44 VSL
USB Stream Output

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

card 0: sofsoundwire [sof-soundwire], device 2: Speaker (*) []
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: sofsoundwire [sof-soundwire], device 5: HDMI 1 (*) []
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: sofsoundwire [sof-soundwire], device 6: HDMI 2 (*) []
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: sofsoundwire [sof-soundwire], device 7: HDMI 3 (*) []
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 1: VSL [AudioBox 44 VSL], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

amixer -c0

Simple mixer control 'Speaker',0
Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
Playback channels: Mono
Mono: Playback [on]

Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
Playback channels: Mono
Mono: Playback [on]

Simple mixer control 'IEC958',1
Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
Playback channels: Mono
Mono: Playback [on]

Simple mixer control 'IEC958',2
Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
Playback channels: Mono
Mono: Playback [on]

Simple mixer control 'PGA3.1 3 Master',0
Capabilities: pvolume
Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
Limits: Playback 0 - 32
Mono:
Front Left: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
Front Right: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]

Simple mixer control 'PGA5.0 5 Master',0
Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
Limits: Capture 0 - 80
Front Left: Capture 50 [62%] [0.00dB] [on]
Front Right: Capture 50 [62%] [0.00dB] [on]

Simple mixer control 'PGA6.0 6 Master',0
Capabilities: pvolume
Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
Limits: Playback 0 - 32
Mono:
Front Left: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
Front Right: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]

Simple mixer control 'PGA7.0 7 Master',0
Capabilities: pvolume
Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
Limits: Playback 0 - 32
Mono:
Front Left: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
Front Right: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]

Simple mixer control 'PGA8.0 8 Master',0
Capabilities: pvolume
Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
Limits: Playback 0 - 32
Mono:
Front Left: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
Front Right: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]

Simple mixer control 'rt1316-1 DAC',0
Capabilities: pswitch
Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
Mono:
Front Left: Playback [on]
Front Right: Playback [on]

Simple mixer control 'rt1316-1 Isense Mixer',0
Capabilities: pswitch
Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
Mono:
Front Left: Playback [on]
Front Right: Playback [on]

Simple mixer control 'rt1316-1 Left I Tag Select',0
Capabilities: volume volume-joined
Playback channels: Mono
Capture channels: Mono
Limits: 0 - 7
Mono: 2 [29%]

Simple mixer control 'rt1316-1 Left V Tag Select',0
Capabilities: volume volume-joined
Playback channels: Mono
Capture channels: Mono
Limits: 0 - 7
Mono: 0 [0%]

Simple mixer control 'rt1316-1 RX Channel Select',0
Capabilities: enum
Items: 'L,R' 'L,L' 'L,R' 'L,L+R' 'R,L' 'R,R' 'R,L+R' 'L+R,L' 'L+R,R' 'L+R,L+R'
Item0: 'L,L'

Simple mixer control 'rt1316-1 Right I Tag Select',0
Capabilities: volume volume-joined
Playback channels: Mono
Capture channels: Mono
Limits: 0 - 7
Mono: 3 [43%]

Simple mixer control 'rt1316-1 Right V Tag Select',0
Capabilities: volume volume-joined
Playback channels: Mono
Capture channels: Mono
Limits: 0 - 7
Mono: 1 [14%]

Simple mixer control 'rt1316-1 Vsense Mixer',0
Capabilities: pswitch
Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
Mono:
Front Left: Playback [on]
Front Right: Playback [on]

Simple mixer control 'rt1316-1 XU24 Bypass',0
Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
Playback channels: Mono
Mono: Playback [off]

Simple mixer control 'rt1316-2 DAC',0
Capabilities: pswitch
Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
Mono:
Front Left: Playback [on]
Front Right: Playback [on]

Simple mixer control 'rt1316-2 Isense Mixer',0
Capabilities: pswitch
Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
Mono:
Front Left: Playback [on]
Front Right: Playback [on]

Simple mixer control 'rt1316-2 Left I Tag Select',0
Capabilities: volume volume-joined
Playback channels: Mono
Capture channels: Mono
Limits: 0 - 7
Mono: 2 [29%]

Simple mixer control 'rt1316-2 Left V Tag Select',0
Capabilities: volume volume-joined
Playback channels: Mono
Capture channels: Mono
Limits: 0 - 7
Mono: 0 [0%]

Simple mixer control 'rt1316-2 RX Channel Select',0
Capabilities: enum
Items: 'L,R' 'L,L' 'L,R' 'L,L+R' 'R,L' 'R,R' 'R,L+R' 'L+R,L' 'L+R,R' 'L+R,L+R'
Item0: 'R,R'

Simple mixer control 'rt1316-2 Right I Tag Select',0
Capabilities: volume volume-joined
Playback channels: Mono
Capture channels: Mono
Limits: 0 - 7
Mono: 3 [43%]

Simple mixer control 'rt1316-2 Right V Tag Select',0
Capabilities: volume volume-joined
Playback channels: Mono
Capture channels: Mono
Limits: 0 - 7
Mono: 1 [14%]

Simple mixer control 'rt1316-2 Vsense Mixer',0
Capabilities: pswitch
Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
Mono:
Front Left: Playback [on]
Front Right: Playback [on]

Simple mixer control 'rt1316-2 XU24 Bypass',0
Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
Playback channels: Mono
Mono: Playback [off]

Simple mixer control 'rt714 ADC 22 Mux',0
Capabilities: enum
Items: 'MIC1' 'MIC2' 'LINE1' 'LINE2' 'DMIC1' 'DMIC2' 'DMIC3' 'DMIC4'
Item0: 'DMIC3'

Simple mixer control 'rt714 ADC 23 Mux',0
Capabilities: enum
Items: 'MIC1' 'MIC2' 'LINE1' 'LINE2' 'DMIC1' 'DMIC2' 'DMIC3' 'DMIC4'
Item0: 'DMIC4'

Simple mixer control 'rt714 ADC 24 Mux',0
Capabilities: enum
Items: 'MIC2' 'DMIC1' 'DMIC2' 'DMIC3' 'DMIC4'
Item0: 'MIC2'

Simple mixer control 'rt714 ADC 25 Mux',0
Capabilities: enum
Items: 'MIC1' 'DMIC1' 'DMIC2' 'DMIC3' 'DMIC4'
Item0: 'MIC1'

Simple mixer control 'rt714 FU02',0
Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right - Rear Left - Rear Right
Limits: Capture 0 - 127
Front Left: Capture 119 [94%] [270.00dB] [on]
Front Right: Capture 119 [94%] [270.00dB] [on]
Rear Left: Capture 119 [94%] [270.00dB] [on]
Rear Right: Capture 119 [94%] [270.00dB] [on]

Simple mixer control 'rt714 FU06',0
Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right - Rear Left - Rear Right
Limits: Capture 0 - 127
Front Left: Capture 47 [37%] [0.00dB] [off]
Front Right: Capture 47 [37%] [0.00dB] [off]
Rear Left: Capture 47 [37%] [0.00dB] [off]
Rear Right: Capture 47 [37%] [0.00dB] [off]

Simple mixer control 'rt714 FU0A',0
Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
Limits: Capture 0 - 127
Front Left: Capture 47 [37%] [0.00dB] [off]
Front Right: Capture 47 [37%] [0.00dB] [off]

Simple mixer control 'rt714 FU0C Boost',0
Capabilities: volume
Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right - Rear Left - Rear Right - Front Center - Woofer - Side Left - Side Right
Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right - Rear Left - Rear Right - Front Center - Woofer - Side Left - Side Right
Limits: 0 - 3
Front Left: 0 [0%]
Front Right: 0 [0%]
Rear Left: 0 [0%]
Rear Right: 0 [0%]
Front Center: 0 [0%]
Woofer: 0 [0%]
Side Left: 0 [0%]
Side Right: 0 [0%]

Simple mixer control 'rt714 FU0E Boost',0
Capabilities: volume
Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right - Rear Left - Rear Right - Front Center - Woofer - Side Left - Side Right
Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right - Rear Left - Rear Right - Front Center - Woofer - Side Left - Side Right
Limits: 0 - 3
Front Left: 0 [0%]
Front Right: 0 [0%]
Rear Left: 0 [0%]
Rear Right: 0 [0%]
Front Center: 0 [0%]
Woofer: 0 [0%]
Side Left: 0 [0%]
Side Right: 0 [0%]

pacmd list-cards

2 card(s) available.

```
index: 0
name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
owner module: 23
properties:
    alsa.card = "0"
    alsa.card_name = "sof-soundwire"
    alsa.long_card_name = "Intel Soundwire SOF"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_soc_sof_sdw"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3-platform-sof_sdw"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sof_sdw/sound/card0"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "8086"
    device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
    device.product.id = "51ca"
    device.string = "0"
    device.description = "sof-soundwire"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
profiles:
    HiFi: Play HiFi quality Music (priority 40768, available: unknown)
    off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
active profile: <HiFi>

sinks:

    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw.HiFi__hw_sofsoundwire_7__sink/#1: sof-soundwire HDMI / DisplayPort 3 Output

    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw.HiFi__hw_sofsoundwire_6__sink/#2: sof-soundwire HDMI / DisplayPort 2 Output

    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw.HiFi__hw_sofsoundwire_5__sink/#3: sof-soundwire HDMI / DisplayPort 1 Output

    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw.HiFi__hw_sofsoundwire_2__sink/#4: sof-soundwire Speaker

sources:
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw.HiFi__hw_sofsoundwire_7__sink.monitor/#1: Monitor of sof-soundwire HDMI / DisplayPort 3 Output

    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw.HiFi__hw_sofsoundwire_6__sink.monitor/#2: Monitor of sof-soundwire HDMI / DisplayPort 2 Output

    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw.HiFi__hw_sofsoundwire_5__sink.monitor/#3: Monitor of sof-soundwire HDMI / DisplayPort 1 Output

    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw.HiFi__hw_sofsoundwire_2__sink.monitor/#4: Monitor of sof-soundwire Speaker

    alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw.HiFi__hw_sofsoundwire_4__source/#5: sof-soundwire SoundWire microphones

ports:
    [Out] HDMI3: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 Output (priority 700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            
    [Out] HDMI2: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 Output (priority 600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            
    [Out] HDMI1: HDMI / DisplayPort 1 Output (priority 500, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
        properties:
            device.product.name = "E321VL"

    [Out] Speaker: Speaker (priority 100, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:
            
    [In] Mic: SoundWire microphones (priority 100, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:
            
index: 3
name: <alsa_card.usb-PreSonus_AudioBox_44_VSL_2256-00>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
owner module: 29
properties:
    alsa.card = "1"
    alsa.card_name = "AudioBox 44 VSL"
    alsa.long_card_name = "PreSonus AudioBox 44 VSL at usb-0000:00:14.0-3.2, high speed"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3.2:1.0"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3.2/3-3.2:1.0/sound/card1"
    udev.id = "usb-PreSonus_AudioBox_44_VSL_2256-00"
    device.bus = "usb"
    device.vendor.id = "194f"
    device.vendor.name = "PreSonus Audio Electronics, Inc."
    device.product.id = "0102"
    device.product.name = "AudioBox 44 VSL"
    device.serial = "PreSonus_AudioBox_44_VSL_2256"
    device.string = "1"
    device.description = "AudioBox 44 VSL"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
profiles:
    input:multichannel-input: Multichannel Input (priority 1, available: unknown)
    output:analog-surround-40: Analog Surround 4.0 Output (priority 1200, available: unknown)
    output:analog-surround-40+input:multichannel-input: Analog Surround 4.0 Output + Multichannel Input (priority 1201, available: unknown)
    off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
active profile: <output:analog-surround-40+input:multichannel-input>

sinks:

    alsa_output.usb-PreSonus_AudioBox_44_VSL_2256-00.analog-surround-40/#8: AudioBox 44 VSL Analog Surround 4.0

sources:
    alsa_output.usb-PreSonus_AudioBox_44_VSL_2256-00.analog-surround-40.monitor/#13: Monitor of AudioBox 44 VSL Analog Surround 4.0

    alsa_input.usb-PreSonus_AudioBox_44_VSL_2256-00.multichannel-input/#14: AudioBox 44 VSL Multichannel

ports:
    analog-output: Analog Output (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:
```

pacmd list-sinks

5 sink(s) available.

```
index: 1
name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw.HiFi__hw_sofsoundwire_7__sink>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
state: SUSPENDED
suspend cause: IDLE
priority: 9037
volume: front-left: 68810 / 105% / 1.27 dB,   front-right: 68810 / 105% / 1.27 dB
        balance 0.00
base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
volume steps: 65537
muted: no
current latency: 0.00 ms
max request: 0 KiB
max rewind: 0 KiB
monitor source: 1
sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
channel map: front-left,front-right
             Stereo
used by: 0
linked by: 0
configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 341.33 ms
card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw>
module: 23

properties:
    alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
    device.api = "alsa"
    device.class = "sound"
    alsa.class = "generic"
    alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
    alsa.name = ""
    alsa.id = "HDMI 3 (*)"
    alsa.subdevice = "0"
    alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
    alsa.device = "7"
    alsa.card = "0"
    alsa.card_name = "sof-soundwire"
    alsa.long_card_name = "Intel Soundwire SOF"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_soc_sof_sdw"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3-platform-sof_sdw"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sof_sdw/sound/card0"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "8086"
    device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
    device.product.id = "51ca"
    device.string = "_ucm0001.hw:sofsoundwire,7"
    device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
    device.buffering.fragment_size = "16384"
    device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
    device.profile.name = "HiFi: hw:sofsoundwire,7: sink"
    device.profile.description = "HDMI / DisplayPort 3 Output"
    alsa.mixer_device = "_ucm0001.hw:sofsoundwire"
    device.description = "sof-soundwire HDMI / DisplayPort 3 Output"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"

ports:

    [Out] HDMI3: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 Output (priority 700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            
active port: <[Out] HDMI3>

index: 2

name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw.HiFi__hw_sofsoundwire_6__sink>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
state: SUSPENDED
suspend cause: IDLE
priority: 9036
volume: front-left: 85181 / 130% / 6.83 dB,   front-right: 85181 / 130% / 6.83 dB
        balance 0.00
base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
volume steps: 65537
muted: no
current latency: 0.00 ms
max request: 0 KiB
max rewind: 0 KiB
monitor source: 2
sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
channel map: front-left,front-right
             Stereo
used by: 0
linked by: 0
configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 341.33 ms
card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw>
module: 23

properties:
    alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
    device.api = "alsa"
    device.class = "sound"
    alsa.class = "generic"
    alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
    alsa.name = ""
    alsa.id = "HDMI 2 (*)"
    alsa.subdevice = "0"
    alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
    alsa.device = "6"
    alsa.card = "0"
    alsa.card_name = "sof-soundwire"
    alsa.long_card_name = "Intel Soundwire SOF"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_soc_sof_sdw"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3-platform-sof_sdw"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sof_sdw/sound/card0"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "8086"
    device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
    device.product.id = "51ca"
    device.string = "_ucm0001.hw:sofsoundwire,6"
    device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
    device.buffering.fragment_size = "16384"
    device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
    device.profile.name = "HiFi: hw:sofsoundwire,6: sink"
    device.profile.description = "HDMI / DisplayPort 2 Output"
    alsa.mixer_device = "_ucm0001.hw:sofsoundwire"
    device.description = "sof-soundwire HDMI / DisplayPort 2 Output"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"

ports:
    [Out] HDMI2: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 Output (priority 600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            
active port: <[Out] HDMI2>

index: 3

name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw.HiFi__hw_sofsoundwire_5__sink>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
state: SUSPENDED
suspend cause: IDLE
priority: 9035
volume: front-left: 62259 /  95% / -1.34 dB,   front-right: 62259 /  95% / -1.34 dB
        balance 0.00
base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
volume steps: 65537
muted: no
current latency: 0.00 ms
max request: 0 KiB
max rewind: 0 KiB
monitor source: 3
sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
channel map: front-left,front-right
             Stereo
used by: 0
linked by: 0
configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 341.33 ms
card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw>
module: 23

properties:
    alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
    device.api = "alsa"
    device.class = "sound"
    alsa.class = "generic"
    alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
    alsa.name = ""
    alsa.id = "HDMI 1 (*)"
    alsa.subdevice = "0"
    alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
    alsa.device = "5"
    alsa.card = "0"
    alsa.card_name = "sof-soundwire"
    alsa.long_card_name = "Intel Soundwire SOF"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_soc_sof_sdw"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3-platform-sof_sdw"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sof_sdw/sound/card0"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "8086"
    device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
    device.product.id = "51ca"
    device.string = "_ucm0001.hw:sofsoundwire,5"
    device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
    device.buffering.fragment_size = "16384"
    device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
    device.profile.name = "HiFi: hw:sofsoundwire,5: sink"
    device.profile.description = "HDMI / DisplayPort 1 Output"
    alsa.mixer_device = "_ucm0001.hw:sofsoundwire"
    device.description = "sof-soundwire HDMI / DisplayPort 1 Output"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"

ports:
    [Out] HDMI1: HDMI / DisplayPort 1 Output (priority 500, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
        properties:
            device.product.name = "E321VL"
active port: <[Out] HDMI1>

index: 4

name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw.HiFi__hw_sofsoundwire_2__sink>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
state: SUSPENDED
suspend cause: IDLE
priority: 9031
volume: front-left: 68812 / 105% / 1.27 dB,   front-right: 68812 / 105% / 1.27 dB
        balance 0.00
base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
volume steps: 65537
muted: no
current latency: 0.00 ms
max request: 0 KiB
max rewind: 0 KiB
monitor source: 4
sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
channel map: front-left,front-right
             Stereo
used by: 0
linked by: 0
configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 341.33 ms
card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw>
module: 23

properties:
    alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
    device.api = "alsa"
    device.class = "sound"
    alsa.class = "generic"
    alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
    alsa.name = ""
    alsa.id = "Speaker (*)"
    alsa.subdevice = "0"
    alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
    alsa.device = "2"
    alsa.card = "0"
    alsa.card_name = "sof-soundwire"
    alsa.long_card_name = "Intel Soundwire SOF"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_soc_sof_sdw"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3-platform-sof_sdw"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sof_sdw/sound/card0"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "8086"
    device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
    device.product.id = "51ca"
    device.string = "_ucm0001.hw:sofsoundwire,2"
    device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
    device.buffering.fragment_size = "16384"
    device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
    device.profile.name = "HiFi: hw:sofsoundwire,2: sink"
    device.profile.description = "Speaker"
    alsa.mixer_device = "_ucm0001.hw:sofsoundwire"
    device.description = "sof-soundwire Speaker"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
ports:
    [Out] Speaker: Speaker (priority 100, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:
            
active port: <[Out] Speaker>
```

- index: 8

  name: <alsa_output.usb-PreSonus_AudioBox_44_VSL_2256-00.analog-surround-40>
  driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
  flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
  state: SUSPENDED
  suspend cause: IDLE
  priority: 9049
  volume: front-left: 62257 /  95% / -1.34 dB,   front-right: 62379 /  95% / -1.29 dB,   rear-left: 62257 /  95% / -1.34 dB,   rear-right: 62317 /  95% / -1.31 dB
  balance 0.00
  base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
  volume steps: 65537
  muted: no
  current latency: 0.00 ms
  max request: 0 KiB
  max rewind: 0 KiB
  monitor source: 13
  sample spec: s32le 4ch 44100Hz
  channel map: front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right
  Surround 4.0
  used by: 0
  linked by: 0
  configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
  card: 3 <alsa_card.usb-PreSonus_AudioBox_44_VSL_2256-00>
  module: 29

  properties:
  alsa.resolution_bits = "32"
  device.api = "alsa"
  device.class = "sound"
  alsa.class = "generic"
  alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
  alsa.name = "USB Audio"
  alsa.id = "USB Audio"
  alsa.subdevice = "0"
  alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
  alsa.device = "0"
  alsa.card = "1"
  alsa.card_name = "AudioBox 44 VSL"
  alsa.long_card_name = "PreSonus AudioBox 44 VSL at usb-0000:00:14.0-3.2, high speed"
  alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
  device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3.2:1.0"
  sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3.2/3-3.2:1.0/sound/card1"
  udev.id = "usb-PreSonus_AudioBox_44_VSL_2256-00"
  device.bus = "usb"
  device.vendor.id = "194f"
  device.vendor.name = "PreSonus Audio Electronics, Inc."
  device.product.id = "0102"
  device.product.name = "AudioBox 44 VSL"
  device.serial = "PreSonus_AudioBox_44_VSL_2256"
  device.string = "surround40:1"
  device.buffering.buffer_size = "1411200"
  device.buffering.fragment_size = "705600"
  device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
  device.profile.name = "analog-surround-40"
  device.profile.description = "Analog Surround 4.0"
  device.description = "AudioBox 44 VSL Analog Surround 4.0"
  module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
  device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"

  ports:
  analog-output: Analog Output (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
  properties:

  active port:

pacmd list-sink-inputs
0 sink input(s) available.

pacmd list-source-outputs
0 source output(s) available.